# ¿Qué pasa si no inicializo un objeto con su constructor pero luego en otro proceso lo lleno? Error en una inicialización de variable

Tags: java, objeto, instancias

Estoy haciendo un programa donde inicializo unos objetos sin su constructor pero luego en un switch si los lleno, mi pregunta es porque el programa no funciona y porque al crear una variable float alumno_1.edad dice que no se ha inicializado dicha variable.
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Alumno {
    float edad;
    float altura;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Alumno alumno_1;
        Alumno alumno_2;
        Alumno alumno_3;
        Alumno alumno_4;
        Alumno alumno_5;
        

        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++){
            System.out.println("Ingrese la edad (numero entero) y la altura en metros (numeros decimales digitados con \",\") del alumno numero "+i+".");
            switch(i){
                case 1: alumno_1 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 2: alumno_2 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 3: alumno_3 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 4: alumno_4 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 5: alumno_5 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                default: break;
            }
        }
        Alumno alumno_1.edad;
        


    }

    //constructor
    public Alumno(int _edad, float _altura) {
        this.edad = _edad;
        this.altura = _altura;
    }


    
    
}
```

Comment: Esto: `Alumno alumno_1.edad;` no tiene ningún sentido. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer ahí? Luego, no veo declarados los miembros de tu clase `Alumno` ¿? Tampoco tiene sentido meter el `main` en una clase que representaría una entidad (`Alumno`) de tu programa.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores en tu código.

1. Estás declarando la propiedad `edad` como `float` en la clase y el parámetro de la misma como `int` en el constructor.
2. No estás planteando bien el diseño mismo de la clase. Una clase que representa una **entidad** de la aplicación, como sería `Alumno`, o `Profesor`, `Clase`, `Materia`, etc, debe ser pensada como un molde que usarías para construir objetos de ese tipo. Poner un método `main`, y además un `Scanner` dentro de la clase no tiene ningún sentido. El método `main` es el punto de entrada de la aplicación, por tanto no es parte intrínseca de un `Alumno`, tampoco un `Scanner` es parte intrínseca. Ambas cosas son parte de un **contexto** que puede tener o no relación con la clase, por tanto, ambas cosas deberían quedar fuera.
3. Esto no tiene ningún sentido: `Alumno alumno_1.edad;`, tampoco se entiende lo que quieres hacer ahí ¿? Si es obtener el dato, generalmente las propiedades de la clase se declaran como `private` y defines métodos *getter* para obtener los datos. Por otra parte, en ese contexto ya no tienes que indicar de qué tipo es ese objeto, eso ya fue definido al principio, ahí solamente usarías `alumno_1` seguido del método o propiedad que quieras invocar/modificar.

Tu programa podría quedar así, si aplicamos lo dicho:

### Clase `Alumno`

```
class Alumno

{
    public int edad;
    public float altura;
    
    public Alumno(int _edad, float _altura) 
    {
        this.edad = _edad;
        this.altura = _altura;
    }

    public int getEdad()
    {
        return this.edad;
    }
    
    public float getAltura()
    {
        return this.altura;
    }
}
```

---

### Clase `Principal` ... o cualquier otra

```
public class Principal 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Alumno alumno_1;
        Alumno alumno_2;
        Alumno alumno_3;
        Alumno alumno_4;
        Alumno alumno_5;
        
        for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingrese la edad (numero entero) y la altura en metros (numeros decimales digitados con \",\") del alumno numero "+i+".");
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1: alumno_1 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 2: alumno_2 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 3: alumno_3 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 4: alumno_4 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                case 5: alumno_5 = new Alumno(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextFloat()); break;
                default: break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(alumno_1.getEdad());
    }
}
```

Comment: Esas variables de tipo `Alumno` deben inicializarce cuando se declaran porque en ese caso el compilador no puede garantizar que luego se vaya a hacer.